# npm - can I publish npm package to my server?

Tags: npm

I am interested in npm and start researching about it.

I am wondering if we can host the npm locally?

For example, instead of publishing the npm package to the npm homepage, can we do it locally or publish the npm package to our server.

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Have a look at the `npm registry` here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/registry
Basically, you can set up a private/internal npm registry and consume it using the `--registry` option.

### How

A lot of companies have their own internal npm registry. There are a lot of commercial products with which you can set up an internal npm registry easily.
One of the examples is Artifactory from jFrog.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry

There are also some open-source products as well. For example:
https://github.com/local-npm/local-npm

### `npm install <folder>`

I would also like to mention under some scenarios, instead of an internal registry, install from a local folder is always an option. `npm install <folder>`

Comment: thank you for the answer, I will give it a try